# html and body height confusion

Tags: asp.net

I have this simple code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<body bgcolor="#000000">
</body>

</html>
```

Questions

1. Why I am getting html height 8px in Chrome and Firefox? HTML height should be auto (0px).
2. The body height is 0px, so why is the background color (black) filling the whole screen?

Comment: @Tony Hinkle: I am not sure how are you setting the height. Are you using some css?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before I answer your questions let me tell you that even browsers have their default CSS style which is applied to every webpage! (To give you more insight let's say these default styles are the reason why normal HTML Buttons appear differently in Chrome, Firefox and IE)

**Now for your first question:** As per browser's default CSS HTML has padding of 4px! That's why you are getting HTML height 8px.

Now you must be wondering how to get rid of them? So for that we can use [Normalize CSS](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/)

**Now for your second question:** you can say BODY is the special case tag which has a exceptional way of rendering it's background! (Or say it's not like a normal DIV tag)
In the absence of a background on the html element, the body background will cover the page. If there is a background on the html element, the body background behaves just like any other element.

You can read more about it [here](https://css-tricks.com/just-one-of-those-weird-things-about-css-background-on-body/)

Hope you found your answers.

Answer (score 0):

You have a line break:

```
<body bgcolor="#000000">
                        ^---- here
</body>
```

which gets rendered as a space character, causing you to have an implicit single line of text in your page.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the page using Chrome devtools, you'll see that the 8px height is coming from the user-agent stylesheet; that is, browsers apply their own default styles.
One common technique to wipe this away and start from a 'clean slate' is to use one of the many css reset libs.
See [here](http://cssreset.com/) for some options.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting margin as 8px, not the height. Each browser has some default settings that's why you are seeing that. Check out the default settings for each browser using the below links:

[Firefox](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/layout/style/html.css)

[Webkit](http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Source/WebCore/css/html.css)

[IE](http://www.iecss.com/)